# How to hide UpdateProgress Image

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have one Ajax UpdateProgress for many UpdatePanels in the page. One of the updatepanel's has a gridview with a download button. Once user clicks on the button, the 'wait' Image shows up, but keeps showing even after the download is complete.

How should I hide it, once the download is done.

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:UpdateProgress Id="UpdateProgress1"  runat="server" DisplayAter="1">
    <ProgressTemplate>
        <asp:Image id="imgWait" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/wait.gif"/>
    </ProgressTemplate>  
</asp:UpdateProgress>
```

**JS:**

```
function HideImage()
{
    $(#imgWait).hide();
}
//Also tried
//Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);

//function EndRequestHandler(sender, args)
//{
//   document.getElementById('<%=imgWait.ClientID%>').className = 'hidden';
//}
```

**Code Behind:**

```
protected void Download(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    string sFile = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
    Response.Redirect("Download.Aspx?file="+sFile,false);
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page,this.GetType(),
                                    "script","HideImage();",true);
}
```

**Download.Aspx**

```
page_load()
{
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["file"]))
    {
        string path = Server.MapPath(Request.QueryString["file"]);
        System.IO.FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(path);
        if ( file.Exists )   
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" +  
                              file.Name);
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
            Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
            Response.WriteFile(file.FullName);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are redirecting to a page that downloads a file, I think the screen doesn't really update in that case, so the image stays.

You could either make the file download on the same page or make the redirect via script after the postback:

```
protected void Download(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    string sFile = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
    string script = "location.href='Download.Aspx?file=" + sFile + "';";
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page,this.GetType(),
                                    "script",script,true);
}
```

In this case, the "HideImage()" script is not needed, as the postback would probably complete successfully.

Comment: The compiler, didnt go to the download page at all. So, i put the same code in 'download()'. It says, Native frame is on top of call stack. If that is wrong, could you plz tell, how to make the download on the same page?

Comment: There was an error on the `string script` line, I updated the answer, give it a try.

Comment: That worked, but a new problem came up. The gridview has 2 columns view,delete and both have icons for all rows. After I click on the view icon of any row, it downloads the file, But, all the icons in the grid vanish, after the file is downloaded. I could still download files clicking on that empty area though.

Comment: Try making the download on the same page, [http://geeksaddictions.wordpress.com/2011/12/11/updatepanel] (example).

Comment: This is the working link - http://geeksaddictions.wordpress.com/2011/12/11/updatepanel/#more-1

Comment: Tried this but the icons still dissappear - `ImageButton ib = (ImageButton)sender; if(ib!=null) ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page).RegisterPostBackControl(ib);`